# (tensorflow 2.4.1)how to get a ragged tensor has determinate last dimension shape？

Tags: tensorflow, ragged-tensors

like this:
'''

```
a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
b = [[a, a, a, a], [a, a, a], [a, a, a, a, a, a, a], [a, a]]
c = tf.ragged.constant(b, dtype=tf.float32)
```

'''
I got a tensor with shape : [4, None, None], but i expect [4, None, 3],

Answer (score 3):

You can specify how many ragged dimensions the tensor should have using `ragged_rank`:

```py
a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
b = [[a, a, a, a], [a, a, a], [a, a, a, a, a, a, a], [a, a]]
c = tf.ragged.constant(b, dtype=tf.float32, ragged_rank=1) #<--here
c.shape

>>> TensorShape([4, None, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor#uniform_inner_dimensions_2), to get a uniform inner dimension on a ragged tensor, you need to start from a multidimensional tensor of values so TensorFlow *knows* that dimension is uniform

For your example case, you would want to start by making `b` a 16x3 matrix and then using one of the "from_row_" methods (e.g. `tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths()`) to partition it into your ragged splits. E.g. something like

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
b = np.tile(a, (16,1))
c = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(values= b, row_lengths = [4,3,7,2])
```

should get you the ragged tensor you want with shape `[4,None,3]`.